# How to add few images to Foundation 6 tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, tooltip, zurb-foundation

i'm using foundation 6 tooltip. Guide to documentation i write something like this:

```
span.has-tip aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" data-template="<img src='bonus.like_user_avatars' class='tooltip'>" title=""  Like
```

In ***bonus.like_user_avatars*** i'm keeping a strings of avatars path splitting by **;** 
How should I add them all to one tooltip?

Comment: is bonus.like_user_avatars a javascript object that you're going to be filling in dynamically?  Or (based on your prior question) a ruby object that you're rendering on the server side?

Comment: @kball its a ruby object; i think it does't matter here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the template, you're essentially generating arbitrary HTML to insert, so you should be able to generate that template with all of the images.  It looks like you're using slim which I'm not as familiar with, but in ERB I'd do something like

```
<% @images = bonus.like_user_avatars.map {|src| "<img src='#{src}'/>".join('') } %>
<span class="has-tip" aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" data-template="<div class='tooltip'><%= @images %></div>" title="">Like</span>
```

Comment: I have a problem with your answer.  @images is array of string(like 1)<"img src=......>), and when I pass it to data-template it seems like to be an array with [ ], so images in tooltip is with this brackets. In browser it looks like: [*brackets*  avatar, avatar, avatar, *end bracket* ]

Comment: Sorry about that @DamirNurgaliev, updating the answer slightly to fix